# Reactfire fails in Next/React app due to "Attempted import error"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, react-context, reactfire

I'm wrapping the children of my Next root layout with the Reactfire providers I need:

```
import './globals.css';
import { AuthProvider, FirebaseAppProvider } from 'reactfire';
import { auth, firebaseConfig } from '../config/firebase';

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (

        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <FirebaseAppProvider firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}>
                    <AuthProvider sdk={auth}>
                        {children}
                    </AuthProvider>
                </FirebaseAppProvider>
            </body>
        </html>

    )
}
```

`firebaseConfig` is correct as I can connect to my Firebase app successfully using the `firebase` module.

When I run `npm run dev` it fails with the following error:

Import trace for requested module:

```
../node_modules/reactfire/dist/index.js
./src/app/layout.tsx
- error ../node_modules/reactfire/dist/index.js
Attempted import error: 'createContext' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'f').
```

I tried updating npm, downgrading to the previous Reactfire version, clearing npm cache, reinstalling all node modules, and using the exact setup structure given by Reactfire docs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and tried to downgrade to some later version, which provided some hints that would be helpful in this error message. For me, the issue was that I was configuring the `FirebaseAppProvider` in the entry point of my app, just like you. However, `FirebaseAppProvider` uses useContext, which is a client side feature. This means that the file needs a `'use client'` annotation at the top of the file.

Further complicating this is the fact that you can't just smack `'use client'` at the top of the of the `layout.tsx`-file (can't remember exactly why).

I solved the issue by creating a separate component `Providers` where I placed the `FirebaseAppProvider` and added the `'use client'` annotation at the top of the file, like so:

```
// app/providers.tsx
'use client' //<- REMEMBER THIS

import { FirebaseAppProvider } from 'reactfire'

export function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const firebaseConfig = {
        ...
    };


    return (
        <FirebaseAppProvider firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}>
            {children}
        </FirebaseAppProvider>
    )
}
```

Then, I could use it in my `layout.tsx`-file like so:

```
//app/layout.tsx
import { Providers } from './providers'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Providers>
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps!